# Ripple emulator freezes on startup

Tags: blackberry, ripple

I've been using Ripple (v0.9xx) for developing Blackberry apps using the Webworks SDK (v 2.3.x.x) but just a little while ago, Ripple has stopped working and only freezes when I try to load it up. If I uninstall and reinstall, it starts successfully but then crashes when I try to load an app into the emulator. After that, it will only freeze again whenever I start it. This continues until I decide to uninstall and reinstall after which the cycle starts again.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Here's the fix that I found at:http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/forums/3/topics/77

This problem seems to be related to the use of localstorage. It can be fixed by going to "C:\Users\[username]\Application Data\Research In Motion\Ripple" (or "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Research In Motion\Ripple"  on Windows 7) then deleting the .db files in the 'localhost' and 'developer.blackberry.com' folders. Start Ripple once, see the 'crash' screen, close it (don't bother to press the Fire button) and then reopen it to see it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the standalone version of Ripple. We have not switched back to a Chrome extension model with significantly improved performance and stability. You can download the latest version from here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple

Ripple should auto-update for future releases from that point on.

Comment: Yes I am using the standalone version of Ripple. Did you mean to say "we have now switched back...."? The way you said it seems like you are suggesting I only use the standalone version. Is that correct?

Anyway, I discovered that this happens not only because of localstorage but because I opened Ripple when I did not have an internet connection. This issue is documented here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_release_notes/ripple_rn_1.0beta_1885827_11.html